# Can not import any archive file to siebel tools

Tags: siebel

I have the following problem:

During archive import through tools I encounter the following error:

> An error has occurred preparing a Sql statement.
>
> Please continue or ask your systems administrator to check your application configuration if the problem persists.(SBL-DBC-00108)
>
> ORA-00904: "T3"."SYNC_SUCCESS_FLG": invalid identifier

I looked at the logs T3 is `S_EMP_PER table`, and `"SYNC_SUCCESS_FLG"` does not even exist in this table. I don't know why it is referencing this column.

How could I resolve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, the SIF file came from a different version of Siebel, different from the one you are importing into. Or it could be that the table S_EMP_PER is also modified in your project, you may have to get a SIF of the table and import it first, before you import the BC SIF.